# How to replace a specific character in bash

Tags: sed

I want to replace '_v' with a whitespace and the last dot *.* into a dash "-". I tried using

```
sed 's/_v/ /' and tr '_v' ' '
```

Original Text

```
src-env-package_v1.0.1.18
```

output

```
src-en -package 1.0.1.18
```

Expected Output

```
src-env-package 1.0.1-18
```

Comment: This is not "a specific character", and thus `tr` is not a suitable tool for this. It seems you are seeking to replace a specific sequence of characters.

Comment: `_v` is a **string**, not a character. `_` is a character, as is `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `sed` code. Using `sed`'s capability to store matched regex values into temp buffer(called capturing groups) here. Also using `-E` option here to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) for handling regex in better way.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/mu0pcQ/1) for used regex.

```bash
sed -E 's/^(src-env-package)_v([0-9]+\..*)\.([0-9]+)$/\1 \2-\3/' Input_file
```

***OR*** if its a variable value on which you want to run `sed` command then use following:

```bash
var="src-env-package_v1.0.1.18"
sed -E 's/^(src-env-package)_v([0-9]+\..*)\.([0-9]+)$/\1 \2-\3/' <<<"$var"

src-env-package 1.0.1-18
```

---

---

***Bonus solution:*** Adding a `perl` one-liner solution here, using capturing groups concept(as explained above) in `perl` and getting the values as per requirement.

```bash
perl -pe 's/^(src-env-package)_v((?:[0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$/\1 \2-\3/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(.*)_v(.*)\./\1 \2-/' file
```

Use the greed of the `.*` regexp to find the last occurrence of `_v` and likewise `.` and substitute a space for the former and a `-` for the latter.

If one of the conditions may occur but not necessarily both, use:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)_v/\1 /;s/(.*)\./\1-/' file
```